# How to read a string in php from a binary file created from c#'s BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, php

My c# code is writing a binary file like this using BinaryWriter:

```
writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MAGIC")); //5 ascii characters
writer.Write(version.ToString()); // could be any System.Version.ToString(): "1.2.3.4" or "1.2" or "1.1.1.11", etc
writer.Write(hash); // byte[20]
writer.Write(signature); // byte[256]
// etc.
```

and in PHP I am trying to read it. Right now I am doing this:

```
$myfile = fopen("private/test.txt", "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,5); // read/print the magic file identifier

// problem start
$versionLength = ?????;
//problem end

$versionString = fread($myfile,$versionLength);
.....
```

From what I understand, BinaryWriter will prefix a string with a variable sized value in the [LEB128 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128). How can I read from the binary file this length so that I can read the correct length of the string? I figured I'd find something with Google and searching Stack Overflow, but I had no luck. I tried the unpack variable but had no success.

Comment: There is a lot more in the file than what I posted here. Filesize doesn't relate to the size of this particular string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my coworker wrote a method to do this for me, here it is:

```
function ReadVarInt($file) {
$val = 0;
$bits = 0;
while ($bits != 35) {
    $n = ord(fread($file, 1));
    if ($n === FALSE) return FALSE;
    $val |= ($n & 0x7F) << $bits;
    $bits += 7;
    if (!($n & 0x80))
        return $val;
}
//error "Too many bytes in what should have been a 7 bit encoded Int32.";
return FALSE;
}

function ReadString($file) {
    $len = ReadVarInt($file);
    if ($len === FALSE) return FALSE;
    if ($len < 0) {
        //error "Negative String Length";
        return FALSE;
    }
    return fread($file, $len);
}
```

Simply call like this:

```
$myfile = fopen($filename, "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$string = ReadString($myfile);
```